# How to configure web.config to support file handler

Tags: asp.net

I created a file browser control which open files on client machine itself, so I don't need to bother about file path

from my application I am not able to redirect page to

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files/Application/readme.txt
```

it works for

```
http://
```

how can I configure my application to support file handler.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to redirect to a *local* file. This is not possible without knowing quite a lot of information on the client machine - for example how do you know the directory structure of the client computer?

[`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08za4s98.aspx) tells the client (browser) where to redirect to. A `file` URL will be one that is on the client machine - you would need to know in advance that the file is there, that the user has permissions to view it etc...

---

Are you asking how to send a file from the server?

You can do this via [`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f369a2by.aspx).

Comment: Thanx for reply it is just an example.

Comment: @BreakHead - can you clarify your question then? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Oded - I didn't downvote, but it might be because you state that it's not possible when it is possible. It's just not feasible.

Comment: @Joel - thanks... I am still wondering what the OP actually wants to do, however.